# check a value is exist into jqgrid column or not

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to check some value is exist into jQgrid's column or not . that value will come from some other input text will not come from grid cell.
I need a function to check it.I'm not talking about the existing filtering functionality of jqgrid.
[image]

As Shown Above I need to check 50020000 is exist in that particular column of not.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all row data from grid like following.

```
var allData = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

The you can loop through these data and check for your data is exist or not.

```
$.each(allData, function(i, item){  
    if (item.row1 == text) { //do something }
    if (item.row2 == text) { //do something }
    if (item.row3 == text) { //do something }

    // check for more rows.......    
});
```

Take a look to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12271/) fiddle. Hope this will help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12271/

Comment: Answer is Helpful Azim, need one more help, is it possible the same functionality with jqxGrid also.

Comment: Yes for `jqxGrid` use `$('#grid').jqxGrid('getrows')`.